# How to display a single row from a database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have been looking for ways to display data from a database. However, they all require a loop and I do not want a loop as I only have 1 row in this table.

I came across mysqli_fetch_row() but I am not sure how to implement this. I am starting to learn PHP and MySQL and so any help is appreciated! This is what I have so far...

```
$displayIntro = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Introduction");
$displayTitle = mysqli_fetch_row($displayIntro);

echo $displayTitle['Title'];
echo $displayTitle['Description'];
```

Also after displaying the plain text, how can I format it with HTML? For example, the title will need to be enclosed in `<h1></h1>` and the subscription in paragraph `<p></p>`.

Much thanks to any answers!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Please explain how it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `mysqli_fetch_row` returns enumerated results, array with numeric indexes, so this should be like:

```
$displayIntro = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `Title`,`Description` FROM Introduction");
$displayTitle = mysqli_fetch_row($displayIntro);

echo $displayTitle[0]; // assuming column 'Title' is first row
echo $displayTitle[1]; // assuming column 'Description' is second row
```

What you should use here is `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to fetch a result row as an associative array:

```
$displayIntro = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `Title`,`Description` FROM Introduction");
$displayTitle = mysqli_fetch_assoc($displayIntro);

echo $displayTitle['Title'];
echo $displayTitle['Description'];
```

Use code from @Maximus2012 answer to form html row. Also to get only one row from table with more than one records you can just add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the MySQL query like this:

```
"SELECT `Title`,`Description` FROM Introduction LIMIT 1"
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

From PHP manual entry for mysqli_fetch_row ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)):

"Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero)." The function returns an *enumerated* array, not *associative* array.

Untested, but I would expect this to work:

```
echo $displayTitle[0];
echo $displayTitle[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$displayIntro = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Introduction");
$displayTitle = mysqli_fetch_row($displayIntro);

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<h1>" . $displayTitle['Title'] . "</h1>";
echo "<p>" . $displayTitle['Description'] . "</p>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Comment: So I don't have any errors that are showing which is good. However, when I have inputed this code into my web page, the text from the database doesn't appear. Any ideas on what could cause this?